# ActionBar Cast Button color in Cast v3

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

How to change ActionBar cast button color using Android Cast v3 library? 
I use the following gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.4'
```

In v2 it was sufficient to override ic_media_route_holo_light.xml or mr_ic_media_route_holo_dark.xml from MediaRoute v7, but with Cast v3 it’s not working anymore.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but you can try to [Them.AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278319/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-the-mediaroutebutton-in-the-actionbar/21929118#21929118) in that SO post.

Comment: It was related to cast v2 integration, with v3 it's not working anymore

Answer (score -2):

Try implement for compile, in the new versions the cast is obs