# How to set Button as MediaRouteButton?

Tags: android, chromecast

As we set menuItem as the `MediaRouteButton`,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cast_item_menu, menu);
    mediaRouteMenuItem = CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    return true;
}
```

Is there any way to set a button or an ImageButton as the `MediaRouteButton` in android?

Comment: Have a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278319/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-the-mediaroutebutton-in-the-actionbar) if you haven't already .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally came up with a solution. Hope this will help someone.

**Layout XML file**

Create a `MediaRouteButton` using xml.

```
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/cast"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_google_cast_logo"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

This will create the button you need. Then use it in your activity.

**Activity**

Instantiate the button and set the media button this way.

```
    MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton)findViewById(R.id.cast);
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(),mediaRouteButton);
```

Happy coding...(y)